# mysql query on wp_user and user_meta problem

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works when I have a field view_type = sale but when the view_type = lead it doesn't return any records even when I know there is one. Here is the query...

```
    SELECT a.id, a.user_email, a.user_registered, a.user_login, b1.meta_value AS first_name, b2.meta_value as last_name, b3.meta_value as qualified,
b4.meta_value as referrer,
b5.meta_value as view_type,
b6.meta_value as ref_by,
b7.meta_value as wp_optimizemember_custom_fields
FROM wp_users a
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b1 ON b1.user_id = a.ID AND b1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b2 ON b2.user_id = a.ID AND b2.meta_key = 'last_name'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b3 ON b3.user_id = a.ID AND b3.meta_key = 'qualified'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b4 ON b4.user_id = a.ID AND b4.meta_key = 'referrer'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b5 ON b5.user_id = a.ID AND b5.meta_key = 'view_type'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b6 ON b6.user_id = a.ID AND b6.meta_key = 'ref_by'
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b7 ON b7.user_id = a.ID AND b7.meta_key = 'wp_optimizemember_custom_fields'

WHERE (b4.meta_value LIKE '$user_ID' AND b5.meta_value LIKE 'lead') or
(b6.meta_value LIKE '$user_ID' AND b5.meta_value LIKE 'lead')
```

What wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

In `usermeta` table WordPress stores many serialized data. So direct `meta_value` would not work I think. So try the below query-

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.user_email, 
       a.user_registered, 
       a.user_login, 
       b1.meta_value AS first_name, 
       b2.meta_value AS last_name, 
       b3.meta_value AS qualified, 
       b4.meta_value AS referrer, 
       b5.meta_value AS view_type, 
       b6.meta_value AS ref_by, 
       b7.meta_value AS wp_optimizemember_custom_fields 
FROM   wp_users AS a 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b1 
               ON b1.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b2 
               ON b2.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b2.meta_key = 'last_name' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b3 
               ON b3.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b3.meta_key = 'qualified' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b4 
               ON b4.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b4.meta_key = 'referrer' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b5 
               ON b5.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b5.meta_key = 'view_type' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b6 
               ON b6.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b6.meta_key = 'ref_by' 
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS b7 
               ON b7.user_id = a.id 
                  AND b7.meta_key = 'wp_optimizemember_custom_fields' 
WHERE  ( b4.meta_value LIKE '%{$user_ID}%' 
         AND b5.meta_value LIKE '%lead%' ) 
        OR ( b6.meta_value LIKE '%{$user_ID}%' 
             AND b5.meta_value LIKE '%lead%' )
```

Look here I put all the `meta_value`'s value between two `%`. That means it will take the serialized data and will search it as string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm inserting the data in to the meta values and its just a single string not serialised. So its not working still if you read when I said above, it works when the string is 'sale' and not when its a 'lead'. Pulling my hair out I really need this code fixed.

Comment: Can you give us both the table with data ? Just go to you database administrator and download those tables as SQL file and attach here.

Comment: The files are big and they have real data so it cant be displayed here.

Comment: On which `meta_key` 'lead' does not work and 'sale' works ?

Comment: Bottom line is this there is a record with a 'view_type'  value 'lead' with the right user ID the query is  just not returning anything zero.

Comment: On 'view_type' this can be 'sale' or 'invoice' or 'lead'

Comment: I have spent all day on this problem hope someone can help me.

Comment: I need to see your database, man. Otherwise it's pretty tough to figure it out. A screen shot can help a lot. @Nelson101

Comment: Sorry the last screenshot didn't work here is another one http://imgur.com/6Wkkbg8 @the_dramatist

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was that 1 record didn't have the 'ref_by' meta_key set and with INNER JOINS all must succeed, thats why I wasn't getting a result.